# Docker: Find dockerfile of images

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-image

I'm interested in how some images are build, and would like to know where docker saves the images/Dockerfile. I'm using a Mac and the docker version is 1.9.0. On google I see a lot about `boot2docker` but I don't seem to have that executable. I simply click the `Docker Quickstart terminal` and I can do

```
$> docker run dockerinaction/hello_world
```

I noticed that for the `hello-word` image I can find the dockerfile on `hub.docker.com`, but for [onedio/base-node5](https://hub.docker.com/r/onedio/base-node5/) I can't. Is it possible to find the Dockerfile for base-node5 on hub.docker.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dockerfile-from-images from centurylinkabs, that will create the Dockerfile, see https://github.com/centurylinklabs/dockerfile-from-image

Answer (score 2):

You can get a lot of that info from the [Docker History command](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/)

```
docker history onedio/base-node5
```